# vmware player xorg driver broke after ubuntu 12.04 LTS automatic system update on 06/07/2014

Tags: 12.04, xorg, 64-bit, vmware, gpu-driver

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as a virtual machine on a Windows 7 host using vmware player 6.0.2.

On Sat. 06/07/2014, Ubuntu performed an automatic system update as it does regularly, however after reboot, the display driver seems to be broken which causes the screen to split into many identical panels. This pretty much rendered the VM unusable.

Below is the log entry for that update from `/var/log/apt/history.log`

It appears that at least one of these updates have caused this problem. The exact same problem has been reported on the vmware forum as well, see https://communities.vmware.com/message/2388776#2388776

So far I have not been able so find a solution.

Content in `/var/log/apt/history.log`

```
Start-Date: 2014-06-07  15:04:46
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.65'
Install: linux-headers-3.2.0-64:amd64 (3.2.0-64.97), linux-image-3.2.0-64-generic:amd64 (3.2.0-64.97), linux-headers-3.2.0-64-generic:amd64 (3.2.0-64.97)
Upgrade: iproute:amd64 (20111117-1ubuntu2.1, 20111117-1ubuntu2.3), libknewstuff3-4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkdeclarative5:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libnepomukquery4a:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libgnutls-openssl27:amd64 (2.12.14-5ubuntu3.7, 2.12.14-5ubuntu3.8), libthreadweaver4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkdecore5:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libnepomukutils4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libktexteditor4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), linux-generic:amd64 (3.2.0.63.75, 3.2.0.64.76), libkmediaplayer4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkrosscore4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libgnutls26:amd64 (2.12.14-5ubuntu3.7, 2.12.14-5ubuntu3.8), libgnutls26:i386 (2.12.14-5ubuntu3.7, 2.12.14-5ubuntu3.8), libsolid4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libnepomuk4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkdnssd4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkparts4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), kdoctools:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libssl-dev:amd64 (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.13, 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14), libssl-doc:amd64 (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.13, 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14), libkidletime4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (3.2.0.63.75, 3.2.0.64.76), linux-image-generic:amd64 (3.2.0.63.75, 3.2.0.64.76), libkcmutils4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkfile4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkpty4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkntlm4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libplasma3:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkemoticons4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), kdelibs-bin:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkdewebkit5:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkjsembed4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkio5:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkjsapi4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), openssl:amd64 (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.13, 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14), kdelibs5-data:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.2.0-63.95, 3.2.0-64.97), libkde3support4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libknotifyconfig4:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), kdelibs5-plugins:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkhtml5:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkdeui5:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libkdesu5:amd64 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2, 4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3), libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.13, 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14), libssl1.0.0:i386 (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.13, 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14)
End-Date: 2014-06-07  15:09:08
```

Answer (score 0):

The very same problem happened to me. I was able to circumvent the issue by reverting to a VM snapshot and setting the 8 updates related to the Linux kernel to not install (they are very close to the top of the list of updates). I do not know which of the 8 (or a combination) caused the problem, but those updates are indeed the change that caused the problem with the display.